# Elastic Search - Conditional field query if no match found for another field

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to do conditional field query if match was not found for another field ?

for eg: if I have a 3 fields in the index   local_rating , global_rating and default_rating , I need to first check in local_rating and if there is no match then try for global_rating and finally for default_rating .

is this possible to do with one query ?  or any other ways to achieve this

thanks in advance

Comment: By match on local rating, what are you checking?

Comment: I need to search for records with a given rating but the given rating has to searched against local rating first and if there is no match then global rating. I think I can do an multimatch OR query and then filter at the client side. But wanted to check if this can be done something like conditional query in elasticsearch

Comment: Can you add mapping and sample data

Comment: I will try to add sample data

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about any existing features of Elasticsearh to fulfill your current requirements but you can try with fields and per-fields boosting, Individual fields can be boosted with the caret `(^)`notation. Also I don't know boosting is possible with numeric value or not?

```
 GET /_search
 {
  "query": {
  "multi_match" : {
   "query" : 10,
    "fields" : [ "local_rating^6", "global_rating^3","default_rating"] 
   }
  }
}
```

**See**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#field-boost